# Load environment variables in python

Tags: flask, environment-variables, python-dotenv

**Trying to load environment varibles in python module**

```
import os
    
class Config(object):
    port = os.environ.get("PORT") or 5000
    
print(Config.port)
    
$ 5000
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Help in loading environment variables in python

Answer (score 1):

### This is an easy fix for the problem I just experiences with flask

- Create virtual environment using `pip` or `pipenv` i.e `virtualenv env`
- Activate the virtual environment `source env/bin/acivate`
- Install `python-dotenv` module `pip install python-dotenv`

---

On top of your python file have something like this

In my `.env` file I have a variable named `MY_VARIABLE`

```
MY_VARIABLE=Somevalue
```

#### In my `app.py` I have this

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
# Loading up the values
load_dotenv()
class Config(object):
    port = os.environ.get("MY_VARIABLE") or 5000

print(Config.port)
```

### Output

```
$ Somevalue
```